# GAS: Finding the last column in a given row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following functions. The first, `lastRowF`, finds the last row in a column that you give it. It works perfectly.

```
//Finds last row in a given column
function lastRowF(column) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return lastRow;
}
```

The second, `lastColF`, does the same thing but for columns in a given row. Or at least it should.

```
//Finds last column in a given row
function lastColF(row) {
  var lastCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxColumns();
//  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + row + ":" + colLetter(lastCol) + row).getValues();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:AB2").getValues();

  for (; values[lastCol - 1] == "" && lastCol > 0; lastCol--) {}
  return colLetter(lastCol);
}
```

As it is, the function simply returns `lastCol` as it's originally declared. The `for` loops is exited immediately.

I've determined that `values` is the issue, but I cannot figure out WHY, and it's driving me mad. The array populates correctly - `msgBox(values)` lists all of the values in the row - but attempting to call an individual value simply returns undefined. It doesn't make any sense to me because checking the whole array and individual values in `lastRowF` works perfectly fine.

Comment: `Range#getValues` returns a 2D array. Not a 1D array. Note that you can save yourself some time by using `getLastColumn()` and `getLastRow()` instead of `getMax____()`, since the `Last` equivalents will skip the (possibly many) rows/columns which are empty across all columns/rows. At worst (formula applied to all cells in the dimension), they will take no extra time.

Comment: @tehhowch well damn. I'd completely forgotten that `getLastColumn()` exists. Since `getLastRow()` looks at the entire sheet I couldn't use it for the rows because the column I was checking wasn't necessarily the longest column, and trying to run `getRange().getLastRow()` returns the last cell in the range, regardless of whether or not it's the last cell with data.

Comment: `Sheet#getLastRow` and `Sheet#getLastColumn` both have the same behavior - they return the last element in which there is defined data. If you have an array formula filling an entire column, then that's obviously gonna affect the output of `getLastRow`, just like a row formula would influence `getLastColumn`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this assists the questioner. In any event, it is my favourite bit of code from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) (credit to [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) who in his turn adapted it from another answer to a different question. This is the power of Stack Overflow in action.)

To determine the last row in a single column - (done in 2 lines of code):

```
var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
```

You can do the same thing for Columns by changing the direction of the range.